# How to format my data in php

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, format

I have an array in php, with `print_r` it looks like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 4 [6] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 ) 
)
```

when I do `json_encode($mydata)` it looks like this

`[["2","3","3","1","1","4","1"],["1","2","2","1","1","1","1"]]`

but I need this without the quotes, as the next processing simply needs a dataset like this:

`var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];`

the dataset was never intended to use json standards, I simply need to get my array formatted correctly.

so the question is either "how do I remove quotes from json" which is simply nonstandard invalid json and won't get me the responses I'd need

OR

"how do I format this php array to be like the dataset".

it either involves a different kind of print function in php, or it involves some forloop regex in javascript

Comment: possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938645/remove-double-quote-in-json-encode

Comment: Fix your data. Instead of adding strings to your array, add numbers. (numeric strings are shown like numbers in `print_r`: http://codepad.org/pXzFGWr9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehhh you could try this:

```
$d = array();
foreach($myData as $data) {
    $d[] = "[" . implode(",", $data) . "]";
}
echo "[" . implode(",", $d) . "]";
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/nTveAGWm

Although echoing out `json_encode($myData);` worked as well: http://codepad.org/KTfQHz6s

Comment: thanks, I will probably be going with this, although the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK worked for me, my server is using php 5.2.x so this answer will work better

Comment: @CQM: Again, because it's important: **Fix your data**. If you need numbers, use numbers. Rather map the strings in your array(s) to numbers and then use `json_encode` than manually create JSON.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` flag, this will force all numeric strings to be converted to numbers.

Like so:

```
json_encode($array,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Please note that this flag is only available from PHP version 5.3.3

Comment: Not quite correct. It makes sure that all *numeric strings* are converted to *numbers*. PHP won't convert any data to another data type be default, i.e. you don't have to "protect" your data. Quite a difference. And also: *Available since PHP 5.3.3.*.

Comment: this did work for me, but my server is using php 5.2.x thank you @FelixKling saved me a potential headache

Comment: @FelixKling yes that is indeed correct, my mistake, will edit

Answer (score 0):

The reason json_encode is putting quotes is because the data is a string.
Try this example to view the difference:

```
$arr = array(array(4,5,6), array(8,10, "11"));
print_r($arr);
echo "<br>";
echo json_encode($arr);
```

You can try to use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to parse it as int before json_encoding

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
$c = array(1,2,3);
echo "Non-associative array output: ", json_encode($c), "\n";
```

return this: 
Non-associative array output: [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

using your example string u can do smth like this

```
$arr = json_decode('[["2","3","3","1","1","4","1"],["1","2","2","1","1","1","1"]]');
foreach ($arr as &$val)
    foreach ($val as &$item)
        $item = (int)$item;
var_dump(json_encode($arr));
```

finally i get

```
string(33) "[[2,3,3,1,1,4,1],[1,2,2,1,1,1,1]]"
```