# Remove quotes on a single value regarding key: id of json_encode

Tags: php, json

This is my json_encoded result  `{"id":"1","users":"12325546sw","total":"27","Apps":[{"Row":"37","AppIcon":null,"Apps":"Group Play","DataConsumed":"3","Updated":"2017-12-12 07:16:22"},{"Row":"34","AppIcon":null,"Apps":"Gallery","DataConsumed":"24","Updated":"2017-12-12 07:16:22"}]}`

Just i want to remove quotes of the value of id..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938645/remove-double-quote-in-json-encode

Comment: @casperSL the link you shared it removed the qoutes of all keys in the json result, i just want to remove the qoute of a value regarding id key not all.. just a specific key value

Comment: You can first convert your json string to php array and then update id in foreach and then convert back array to json string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

in the json encode pass the second paramater as `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`

```
json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: tried never worked

Comment: what you're getting?

Comment: same result with qoutes

Comment: i just want to remove qoutes of value of Key: id

Comment: JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK will converts numeric string as number

Comment: i was wrong.. thanks for the ans..

Comment: @ImSarah Did solution worked for me, {
    "id": 1,
    "users": "12325546sw",
    "total": 27,
    "Apps": [
        {
            "Row": 37,
            "AppIcon": null,
            "Apps": "Group Play",
            "DataConsumed": 3,
            "Updated": "2017-12-12 07:16:22"
        },
        {
            "Row": 34,
            "AppIcon": null,
            "Apps": "Gallery",
            "DataConsumed": 24,
            "Updated": "2017-12-12 07:16:22"
        }
    ]
}